# How to stop python selenium webdriver infinite page load

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, python-3.6

i'm trying to load url 
https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/idx/stx/blc/EURO-STOXX-50-Index-Options-46548

however some of the page get infinite loading recently and the time.sleep() function with a selenium.webdriver.execute_script('window.stop()') doesn't sovle the problem.

tried:

```
browser.execute_script('window.stip()')
and browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").sendkeys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

still see the page loading.

```
website_url = 'https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/idx/stx/blc/EURO-STOXX-50-Index-Options-46548'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)
dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maturityDate"]'))
dropdown_len = len(dropdown.options)

for i in range(1, dropdown_len):
    rows = []
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.execute_script('window.stop()')
    # browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").sendkeys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

Comment: what i have to do is manually press the cross 'x' in chrome browser to kill the loading then the code move to next drop down work.

Comment: just to make sure are you putting `browser.execute_script('window.stip()')` in your script instead of `browser.execute_script('window.stop()')`??

Comment: yes, my code snapshot is exactly what i put there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [WebDriverWait method](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), this allows you to specify a timeout wait for an element to be present in the page and if it doesn't appear within the time allocated, you can kill the script or whatever action you wish to take.

The example is from [Selenium's Python documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout for not waiting forever

```
browser.implicitly_wait(60) # 60 seconds to wait && this is only used with chrome
browser.set_page_load_timeout(60) # for other browsers
```

This will throw an exception so you need to do a try except statement like:

```
browser.implicitly_wait(60)

try:
    browser.get('http://www.example.com')
except:
    print "loading exceeded the time limit" # not sure what python version you are using
```

Comment: it works for the first few drop down box selection, then it still keep loading after 4 drop down box refresh.
i used 
browser.implicitly_wait(3)